# operating landline phone via mobile phone

Tags: raspberry-pi, cellphone, telephone

I am making a small DIY project to operate my wired landline phone (twisted copper cable) using my mobile phone. Use cases:

- Dial number on landline via mobile device.
- Receive incoming landline calls via mobile.

I plan to use RaspberryPi. What device can I use to intercept calls on my wired phone and do two way manipulation? (I assume it will be an analog to digital and vice versa device, similar to a modem.)

Comment: As Jasen has answered, an Asterisk setup is what you want. You're basically setting up a pbx.

Answer (score 3):

you want an FXO with USB or ethernet connectivity, probably you want asterisk support too.